# Como convertir un int en identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Imagen1]

[image: Imagen2]

He intentado setear una variable sumando el codigo (max+ 1), pero tampoco me sale.

Una guía sería de gran ayuda

Comment: Por favor, tómese unos minutos y revise [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). La descripción de su pregunta quedó con varios problemas de formato, además, evite las fotos para presentar código. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El identity es una propiedad de la tabla, no de la columna. Por lo tanto, una vez creada la tabla no se puede asignar la propiedad a la columna. Se tiene que crear la tabla desde cero para poder designar la propiedad.

Una alternativa es el uso de los objetos `SEQUENCE`.

Para crearlos, se usa la sentencia CREATE.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ProductoCodigo
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Y la sentencia queda como

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Producto(
    codigo,
    nombre,
    unidad,
    precio,
    stock
)
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ProductoCodigo,
    @nombrePro,
    @unidadPro,
    @precioPro,
    @stockPro
WHERE @precioPro >= 0
AND @stockPro >= 0;
```

Ten en cuenta que esto no cambia las filas ya existentes y habría que asignar un valor de inicio adecuado a la secuencia en caso de que ya haya valores.

Por regla general, No debes alterar las estructuras de los objetos al momento de hacer cambios a los datos (insert, update, delete). Tienes que mantener ambos procesos de forma independiente.